# Regarding online quiz application in asp.net c#

Tags: asp.net

Hi
I am creating online quiz application in asp.net. I have one question & their answers per page. I have next button to display next record for that i have taken random function. but at last question i want submit button once all questions gets finished for particular test & also at the same time review question link to review the questions.
Please help me how to review questions using checkboxes?
Thank you.

Comment: You could store the questionnaire in Session as Dictionary(key QuestionID and value is a List of AnswerIDs).

Answer (score 1):

Try [Building a Quiz Engine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/beginner/bb308879.aspx). It is not a masterpiece of software design (more specifically, columns `Answer1` to `Answer4` is a no-no), but it's a good start.

Comment: I have taken random function for no. of questions to load after clicking next button but here problem is that questions are coming randomly so how i can know which will be last question so that i can have submit button to submit the answers to respective questions